# Android Studio - Cannot resolve symbol FacebookContentProvider

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-contentprovider, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the Facebook SDK 3.22.0 from Maven. Building for Android SDK version 15. I'm also using Android Studio 1.1.0 with Gradle.

In AndroidManifest.xml I'm trying to use the FacebookContentProvider, but every time I try, I get the issue Cannot resolve symbol FacebookContentProvider. Any ideas on how to solve this?

The specific line I'm having an issue with is:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
              android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
              android:exported="true"/>
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.whatever"
android:versionCode="100"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.whatever.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity android:name="com.whatever.Friends"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.whatever.Recent"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
              android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
              android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.whatever"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using ADS with maven, not gradle?

Comment: I'm am using Gradle.

Comment: than provide please content of your 'build.gradle' file

Comment: I edited my question, and added my build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use `FacebookContentProvider` with Facebook SDK version 3.22.0 since it was introduced with version 4.0.0 as you can see on GitHub:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/commits/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/FacebookContentProvider.java

You have two solutions:

- Update Facebook SDK to version 4.0.0 or higher
- Use `NativeAppCallContentProvider` like this:

  ```
  <provider
      android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
      android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider1234"
      android:exported="true" />
  ```

  You can find more information about `NativeAppCallContentProvider` here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.5/class/NativeAppCallContentProvider/

Answer (score 1):

[Quote](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started):

> Append your app id to the end of the authorities value. For example if
>   your Facebook app id is 1234, the declaration looks like:
>
> ```
> <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
>           android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
>           android:exported="true" />
> ```

Are you sure that your app id is 1234? Also why target sdk is 15 well as min sdk is 15? Why are you using not latest facebook sdk? Fix it and I think everything would be ok.

Comment: In my app, I have the correct facebook app id for 1234, I changed it just for this question. I changed my minSdkVersion to 15 and my targetSdkVersion to 21. I'm using that version of the Facebook SDK because the latest one is not working for me.

Comment: In build.gradle, I set: compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'. When I do this, most of my com.facebook imports in my java code suddenly cannot be resolved.

Comment: Just follow this instruction - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started.

Comment: Please, where have I to put the provider code. In the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0):

In v3.x of the Facebook SDK, it was called the NativeAppCallContentProvider, so you need to do something like:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.NativeAppCallContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.NativeAppCallContentProvider{Facebook-App-Id}"
    android:exported="true" />
```

Comment: Please, where can I put this cde? In the AndroidManifest?